# How does Cantor's diagonal argument work with bi-infinite sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, infinity

I understand the basic premise of the argument when considering a list of infinitely long binary sequences; you arrange them in any order, take the inverse of items along a diagonal, and the sequence formed cannot be in the list.

I'm confused on how you can apply this to a bi-infinite sequence, that is, an infinitely long sequence that has no 'first' element, where any selected bit has infinitely many bits before and after it. Can anyone clear this up for me?

Comment: $\dots a_{-3}a_{-2}a_{-1}.a_1a_2a_3\dots$ corresponds to $0.a_1a_{-1}$ $a_2a_{-2}a_3a_{-3}\dots$

Comment: Can't you just write the elements as $a_o,a_{-1},a_1,a_{-2},a_2,...$ and then apply the diagonal argument?

Comment: You can diagonalize in both directions now. Give yourself a bi-infinite sequence $(s_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ of bi-infinite binary strings $s_n = \ldots s^n_{-2} s^n_{-1} s^n_0 s^n_1 s^n_2 \ldots$. Then construct a new string $t$, where $t_n$ is defined to be the negation of $s_n^n$.

Comment: @StevenClark I thought of that, but it seemed to me like that might not be sound since all you're showing is that you can construct a sequence which can't be centered around some specific starting location, when there are infinitely many others you could choose to start with which may have your constructed diagonal sequence.

Comment: ...although it occurs to me that the important part is just that you can choose *any* order for the bits, and regardless of your choice, you can demonstrate a sequence not in the list using that order.

Comment: Can you say precisely what statement you wish to prove about such bi-infinite sequences?